# Terraform ssh error on Google Cloud Instance?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, terraform

I've been fighting through Terraform Provisioner connection issues with ssh today. So far I've tried what I *thought* was working previously with this:

```
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "echo ${google_compute_instance.testing-elastic-1.network_interface.0.access_config.0.assigned_nat_ip}"]
      connection {
        type = "ssh"
        user = "root"
        private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/google_compute_engine")}"
        timeout = "45s"
      }
  }
```

But I keep getting the following error to this.

```
Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
```

I also tried logging in directly to the IP with ssh itself at the terminal.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub 122.122.122.122
```

This worked fine. So I also tried this in the configuration, or what I thought would mimic this in the configuration.

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = [
    "echo ${google_compute_instance.testing-elastic-1.network_interface.0.access_config.0.assigned_nat_ip}"]
    connection {
      type = "ssh"
      user = ""
      private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/google_compute_engine")}"
      timeout = "45s"
    }
}
```

Got another error.

Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

- ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain

So then I tried this.

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = [
    "echo ${google_compute_instance.testing-elastic-1.network_interface.0.access_config.0.assigned_nat_ip}"]
    connection {
      type = "ssh"
      private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/google_compute_engine")}"
      timeout = "45s"
    }
}
```

In the end, it seemed nothing had changed. I was right back with this error message.

```
Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
```

I'm not really sure what else I should have or need for the ssh authentication to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are you have the wrong `sshKey` set in your project.  Assuming you have something like the following attached to either your `provisioner` or `resource`:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "my-host" {
  // ...
  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    agent       = false
    user        = "${var.gce_ssh_user}"
    port        = "${var.gce_ssh_port}"
    timeout     = "5m"
    private_key = "${file("${var.gce_ssh_private_key_file}")}"
  }
  // ...
}
```

You should be able to verify the project's `sshKey`:

`$ gcloud compute project-info describe`

My guess is the `sshKey` values set part of the project aren't well formed according to GCE.  If you step through something like the following you may find the configuration snafu that's causing this problem:

```
$ gcloud compute project-info describe > project.yaml
$ cat project.yaml| egrep 'ssh-' | awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3}' > existing_project_keys.pub
$ awk -v USER="$USER" '{print USER ":" $1 " " $2 " " USER}' .ssh_id_rsa.pub > new_keys.pub
$ cat existing_project_keys.pub >> new_keys.pub
$ gcloud compute project-info add-metadata --metadata-from-file sshKeys=new_keys.pub
```

(or, it could be something simple like you have too many keys loaded into your agent, which is why I've disabled the agent in the `connection` above)

Comment: It was the fact the machine I was attempting to run from had mismatched multiple ssh keys for a multitude of agents. When it came down to it, I grabbed another machine and was able to execute it quickly with your mentioned fix.